# Convert 12 hour (AM/PM) string to 24 Date object using moment js

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a output resulting from a timepicker giving 12 hour format of time.

```
Eg : "1:45 AM (or) "12:15 PM" as **string**
```

Is there a way to parse this string format to 24 hour using moment js back to date object?

Comment: Does it output a date too? Don't think you'll be able to do much with just the time as it doesn't represent a valid date.

Comment: It just outputs a string of time in 12 hour format. But hou can this be converted to 24 hour format of Date object?

Comment: Can you please mark my anwer as accepted if it worked?

Answer (score 150, accepted):

See documentation of [moment js `parse` function](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/)

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bjolja/p2bcm2oa/)

```
var dt = moment("12:15 AM", ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
```

Comment: but i am using hungarian locale. but i got same value without converting moment("02:15 PM", ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm"); // 02:15

Answer (score 21):

**I know that this answer is not for the question (actually it is for the opposite case)**, but I will put it for completeness and if someone (like me) was looking for it. 
In case you want to convert from the `24 Hour system` to `12 Hour system` then you could use the following

```
return moment("13", ["HH"]).format("hh A");
```

the previous code will produce the result `1 PM`

Comment: You can make it more reliable by ``[HH.mm]``. ``` moment("1.12", ["HH.mm"]).format("hh:mm a"); => "01:12 am" ```

Answer (score 20):

Just a little conversation
**"2 PM" to "14.00"**

```
const number = moment("02:00 PM", ["h:mm A"]).format("HH:mm");
console.log(number); // Output = "14.00"
```

**"14.00" to "2 PM"**

```
const number = moment("14.00", ["HH:mm"]).format("hh:mm a");
console.log(number); // Output = "02:00 pm"
```

Comment: please fix a syntax error on the second code , it should be 'HH:mm' instead of HH.mm

Answer (score 2):

```js
var today = new Date();
let options = {  
    hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit"  
};  
console.log(today.toLocaleTimeString("en-us", options));
```

Comment: Your code outputs time in AM/PM format. OP wanted to convert AM/PM to 24h, like "01:00 PM" to "13:00"

Comment: add flag "hour12: false" like this {hour: "2-digit", minute: "2-digit", hour12: false
}

Answer (score 1):

In full calender to show time in 12 hour format like 01:00 PM i used following format - timeFormat: 'hh:mm A'.
"timeFormat" is the property of events of fullcalender.

Same format 'hh:mm A' we can use to format datetime object using momentjs.

Answer (score 1):

```
moment("145","hmm").format("HH:mm");
```

this would result in 01:45

Answer (score 1):

using HH:mm will convert 12 hrs format to 24hrs while using hh:mm will convert 12hrs format

```
moment("12:15 PM").format("HH:mm")
```

Answer (score 1):

Stating your time as HH will give you 24h format, and hh will give 12h format.

You can also find it here in the documentation :https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

```
H, HH       24 hour time
h, or hh    12 hour time (use in conjunction with a or A)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can set the time of a `Date` object using a time `String`.

```js
const date = new Date('1/1/21');
const pm = '2:30 PM';
const am = '11:00 AM';
const noon = '12:00 PM';
const midnight = '12:00 AM';

const mergeDateTime = (date, time) => {
  const parsedTime = moment(time, ['h:mm A']);
  const merged = moment(date).set({
    hours: parsedTime.get('hours'),
    minutes: parsedTime.get('minutes')
  });
  
  return merged.toDate();
};

const resultsList = document.querySelector('#results');

const inputs = [pm, am, noon, midnight];

inputs.forEach((input) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = `${input} ➡ ${mergeDateTime(date, input)}`;
  resultsList.appendChild(li);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<h3>Results</h3>
<ul id=results />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dayjs

```
return dayjs(date as string).format('DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm')
```

you will have :

```
03/03/2021 16:36
```

for more information, you can refer to https://day.js.org/docs/en/display/format