# Fullcalendar : Event Sources 12 Hour data

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I have implemented fullcalendar in my project and it works like a charm.

but there is some changes happend in time format we were using 24 hours format but now we are using 12 hours format. i just want to know that in event sources.

does fullcalendar supports add event in 12 hour format like 04:00 PM ?

Currently it can add and view data like this

```
 $scope.events = [{
        title: 'Move or Resize me',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 10),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 20)
    }];
```

in end time see 14:20 (Mean 2:20PM) so i want to add something like

```
 $scope.events = [{
        title: 'Move or Resize me',
        start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 10),
        end: new Date(y, m, d, 02, 20,PM) // Something like this?
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can parse your date and time string using moment.js library, which is used by FullCalendar:

```
var momentObj = moment("2017-11-28 04:15 PM", ["YYYY-MM-DD h:mm A"]);
alert(momentObj.format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"));
```

Check this: [Convert 12 hour (AM/PM) string to 24 Date object using moment js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26783080/convert-12-hour-am-pm-string-to-24-date-object-using-moment-js)